# Finding table name referfences in SSIS packages

Tags: ssis, query

We are in the process of migration onto a later version of SQL Server, from 2012 to 2016.  Our SSIS packages are deployed to SSISDB, in order to find the tables being referenced by the SSIS packages, we have to open it and go through each SSIS package.
Is there a way to query the table names belonging to SSIS packages?

Dennis

Answer (score 1):

If you check the table [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages], you'll find the packages XML. From there, you can parse the XML (might be quite painful) and extract the  tag.

This might be a good start: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6c31e43f-4f25-476c-8cfa-87f91fbf609e/help-navigating-xml-file-with-sql-nodes-method-against-a-column-of-xml-type?forum=sqlxml

Comment: I can see the table but not the XML containing the package definition (SQL 2016)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this as the base for getting tables and procedures referenced in SSIS (2012)

```
CREATE TABLE #SSIS (  pkg_name varchar(255), pd xml);

INSERT INTO #SSIS
SELECT s.name, CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), packagedata))
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysssispackages] s
WHERE description not in ('System Data Collector Package')
    and description not like '%Auto-generated%'


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 
    'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS DTS)
SELECT 
    IDENTITY(INT,1,1) rn,
    r.pkg_name,
    ISNULL (
        y.Mgr.value('./@DTS:ObjectName[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')
        ,y.Mgr.value('./@DTS:ConnectionString[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') 
        ) AS [Source]
    ,y.Mgr.value('./@DTS:DTSID[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')  as SQLConnection
into #Connections
FROM #SSIS r 
CROSS APPLY pd.nodes('//DTS:ConnectionManager') as y(Mgr)
ORDER BY 1,2

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 
    'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS DTS,
    'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask )
SELECT 
    IDENTITY(INT,1,1) rn,
    r.pkg_name,
    x.c.value('./@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS SQLCmd,
    x.c.value('./@SQLTask:Connection[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS SQLConnection
into #SQL
FROM #SSIS r 
CROSS APPLY pd.nodes('//DTS:ObjectData/SQLTask:SqlTaskData') as x(c)
ORDER BY 1,2


select 
    isnull( s.pkg_name , c.pkg_name )  pkg_name
    ,c.Source
    ,s.SQLCmd
    ,c.rn crn,s.rn srn
from #Connections c
full outer join #SQL s on s.SQLConnection = c.SQLConnection and s.pkg_name = c.pkg_name
order by c.pkg_name, s.pkg_name
```